# Identifying the set of Java EE specs for given requirements - a case for EJB, JPA and REST?

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, jax-rs, websphere-8

I am trying to identify the correct set of technologies to develop an application that supports the following.

1. Provide web service capabilities (preferably REST)
2. Be able to handle updates to multiple data resources in a single transaction
3. Have some of form persistence capability.

Based on these basic requirements, my current plan is to build a REST based service using JAX-RS and JPA to handle persistence and use EJB to be able to handle multiple updates to different resources in a single transaction.

Are these the correct set of technologies or am I making my application bulkier.

Thanks for any suggestions. Finally, the application will be deployed on Websphere Application Server v8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those sound like reasonable technology choices for your project. There are all part of Java EE, which provides a ton of other nice features, too, so it provides some room for your application to "grow" without having to worry about being bogged down with huge numbers of libraries from different vendors. In my opinion, using Java EE is not alone a cause for worry about "bulkiness".

Answer (score 0):

Since the application is going to be deployed onto WebSphere Application Server V8.5 there's no need to constrain yourself with available technologies if they are already a part of the runtime environment.

Having said that I however thought about the developers who will develop the application and may suffer from the time it takes to do frequent restarts, redeployments and such. It's not to say WAS 8.5 can't handle them, but since it's a full-blown application server meant for production environment, it might be too much for your development environment. If so, read on.

There's a lighter profile of WAS available - [WebSphere Application Server 8.5 Liberty Profile](http://wasdev.net). It's based on WebSphere AS's codebase, has a small footprint, and is precisely for customers who know the deployment platform is WAS, but they need a lighter solution on their development laptops.

It might be very well-tailored for your needs and if Eclipse is the IDE you may be pleasantly surprised how much slimmer the development environment became with Liberty Profile.